# object' does not contain a definition for 'x' and no extension method 'x' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I already searched for an answer 2 days now, but i didn't find any good answers.
I hope someone can help me.
Everytime i get the same error message in the view: object' does not contain a definition for 'SprintName' and no extension method 'SprintName' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My ViewModel:

```
public class SprintDataViewModel : IEnumerable
    {
        public string SprintName { get; set; }
        public List<SprintPsps> PspElemente = new List<SprintPsps>();
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class SprintPsps
    {
        public string PspName { get; set; }
        public float PspBudget { get; set; }
        public List<MitarbeiterPsp> Mitarbeiter = new List<MitarbeiterPsp>();

    }

    public class MitarbeiterPsp
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        public float Ist { get; set; }
        public float Soll { get; set; }
        public float Netto { get; set; }
    }
```

Here i pick up the data from the database:

```
public SprintDataViewModel GetTotalEvaluationData()
    {
        var sprintData = new SprintDataViewModel();
        using (db)
        {
            var sprint = db.Sprint.FirstOrDefault(x => x.strDescription == "Sprint1");
            var sprintID = sprint.intSprintID;

            var partProjectData = db.PartprojectData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.intSprintID == sprintID);
            var partprojectUserID = partProjectData.intPartprojectUserID;

            var partprojectUser =
                db.PartprojectUser.FirstOrDefault(x => x.intPartprojectUserID == partprojectUserID);
            var partprojectID = partprojectUser.intPartprojectID;
            var userid = partprojectUser.intUserID;

            var user = db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.intUserID == userid);

            var partproject = db.Partproject.FirstOrDefault(x => x.intPartprojectID == partprojectID);

            var excelrow = db.ExcelRow.FirstOrDefault(x => x.strDescription == "Sprint1");

            /*for (var i = 0; i > 1; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j == 1; j++)
                {*/
                    var sprintPsps = new SprintPsps();
                    /*for (var k = 0; k == 1; k++)
                    {*/
                        var mapsp = new MitarbeiterPsp()
                        {
                            Name = user.strName,
                            Forename = user.strForename,
                            Ist = 51,
                            Soll = 2,
                            Netto = 34
                        };
                        sprintPsps.Mitarbeiter.Add(mapsp);
                    //}
                    sprintPsps.PspName = partproject.strDescription;
                    sprintPsps.PspBudget = (float) partproject.fltBudget;
                    sprintData.PspElemente.Add(sprintPsps);
                //}
                sprintData.SprintName = sprint.strDescription;
            //}
            return sprintData;
        }
    }
```

My Controller:

```
public class EvaluationController : Controller
{
    // GET: Evaluation
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new DBInteractions();
        return View(db.GetTotalEvaluationData());
    }
}
```

Here i pick up the data from the database:

```
public SprintDataViewModel GetTotalEvaluationData()
    {
        var sprintData = new SprintDataViewModel();
        using (db)
        {
            var sprint = db.Sprint.FirstOrDefault(x => x.strDescription == "Sprint1");
            var sprintID = sprint.intSprintID;

            var partProjectData = db.PartprojectData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.intSprintID == sprintID);
            var partprojectUserID = partProjectData.intPartprojectUserID;

            var partprojectUser =
                db.PartprojectUser.FirstOrDefault(x => x.intPartprojectUserID == partprojectUserID);
            var partprojectID = partprojectUser.intPartprojectID;
            var userid = partprojectUser.intUserID;

            var user = db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.intUserID == userid);

            var partproject = db.Partproject.FirstOrDefault(x => x.intPartprojectID == partprojectID);

            var excelrow = db.ExcelRow.FirstOrDefault(x => x.strDescription == "Sprint1");

            /*for (var i = 0; i > 1; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j == 1; j++)
                {*/
                    var sprintPsps = new SprintPsps();
                    /*for (var k = 0; k == 1; k++)
                    {*/
                        var mapsp = new MitarbeiterPsp()
                        {
                            Name = user.strName,
                            Forename = user.strForename,
                            Ist = 51,
                            Soll = 2,
                            Netto = 34
                        };
                        sprintPsps.Mitarbeiter.Add(mapsp);
                    //}
                    sprintPsps.PspName = partproject.strDescription;
                    sprintPsps.PspBudget = (float) partproject.fltBudget;
                    sprintData.PspElemente.Add(sprintPsps);
                //}
                sprintData.SprintName = sprint.strDescription;
            //}
            return sprintData;
        }
    }
```

My View:

```
@using ScrumKST.Models
@model SprintDataViewModel 
@Html.DisplayForModel()

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Auswertung";
}

<h2>Sprint Auswertung</h2>

<table>

    <tr>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SprintName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PspElemente[0].PspName)
        </th>
        <th>
            <h6>IST SOLL</h6>
        </th>
        <th>
            <h6>NETTO</h6>
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SprintName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PspElemente[0].PspName)
            </th>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

The application always fails at 'item.SprintName' and 'item.Pspelemente[0].PspName'.
What is my problem here?

Comment: Note that your model is `SprintDataViewModel`. Note that you're enumerating through `Model`. Note that you implemented `SprintDataViewModel.GetEnumerator()` as `return null`. However this is ANOTHER issue you will face after your code will compile. Your immediate problem is that you're implementing `System.Collection.IEnumerable` which is not strongly typed. It means that `item` is of type `object` (and there isn't any `SprintName` property in `System.Object`). Use `IEnumerable<T>` instead or specify the type in the `foreach` instead of `var` (which is then typed to `object`).

Comment: Great it works! But now i have a problem with the `SprintDataViewModel.GetEnumerator()`. @AdrianoRepetti

Comment: It simply shouldn't be `IEnumerable` (at least juding from your controller and `GetTotalEvaluationData()` prototype) but honestly I din't read `GetTotalEvaluationData()` then I don't know what you're trying to do. If your intent is to enumerate `PspElemente` then do it explicitly.